# Как сохранить и отобразить изображение в PyQt?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, qpushbutton

При нажатии на кнопку "`Загрузить фото`" должно открыться диалоговое окно, в котором можно выбрать фото. 
Потом это же изображение нужно сохранить в другой папке.

Помогите с реализацией.

**main.py**

```
import sys
from uic_file import Ui_Dialog
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import shutil
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.imagePath = ''
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_red.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_green.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_blue.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_all.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_bright.clicked.connect(self.bright)
        self.pushButton_left.clicked.connect(self.rotate)
        self.pushButton_right.clicked.connect(self.rotate)
        self.pushButton_negative.clicked.connect(self.negative)
        self.pushButton_wb.clicked.connect(self.wb)
        self.pushButton_gray.clicked.connect(self.gray)
        self.pushButton_sepia.clicked.connect(self.sepia)
        self.pushButton_contrast.clicked.connect(self.contrast)
        self.pushButton_save.clicked.connect(self.save)
        self.pushButton_download.clicked.connect(self.download)
        self.pushButton_orig.clicked.connect(self.orig)

    def contrast(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        avg = 0
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
                avg += r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114
        avg /= width * height
        lst = []
        for i in range(256):
            temp = int(avg + 2 * (i - avg))
            if temp < 0:
                temp = 0
            elif temp > 255:
                temp = 255
            lst.append(temp)
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
                r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
                draw.point((x, y), (lst[r], lst[g], lst[b]))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def sepia(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                all = (a + b + c) // 3
                a = all + 40 * 2
                b = all + 40
                c = all
                if (a > 255):
                    a = 255
                if (b > 255):
                    b = 255
                if (c > 255):
                    c = 255
                draw.point((i, j), (a, b, c))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def gray(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                all = (a + b + c) // 3
                draw.point((i, j), (all, all, all))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def wb(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                all = a + b + c
                if (all > (((255 - 100) // 2) * 3)):
                    a, b, c = 255, 255, 255
                else:
                    a, b, c = 0, 0, 0
                draw.point((i, j), (a, b, c))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def negative(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                draw.point((i, j), (255 - a, 255 - b, 255 - c))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def bright(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0] + 100
                b = pix[i, j][1] + 100
                c = pix[i, j][2] + 100
                if (a < 0):
                    a = 0
                if (b < 0):
                    b = 0
                if (c < 0):
                    c = 0
                if (a > 255):
                    a = 255
                if (b > 255):
                    b = 255
                if (c > 255):
                    c = 255
                draw.point((i, j), (a, b, c))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def run(self):
        im = Image.open("orig.png")
        pixels = im.load()
        x, y = im.size
        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
                r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
                if (self.sender().text() == 'RED'):
                    pixels[i, j] = r, 0, 0
                elif (self.sender().text() == 'GREEN'):
                    pixels[i, j] = 0, g, 0
                elif (self.sender().text() == 'BLUE'):
                    pixels[i, j] = 0, 0, b
                else:
                    pass
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def rotate(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        if (self.sender().text() == "RIGHT"):
            degree = -90
        else:
            degree = 90
        im2 = im.rotate(degree, expand=True)
        im2.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def save(self):
        if self.imagePath:
            print(self.imagePath)
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, "SaveFileName", "",
                                                      "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)",
                                                      options=options)
            if fileName:
                print("файл для Сохранения: ", fileName)

                shutil.copy(self.imagePath, fileName)  # !!!

    def download(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Select Image", "",
                                                        "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
        pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200))

    def orig(self):
        im = Image.open("orig.png")
        im.save("orig.png")
        self.pixmap.load("orig.png")
        self.current = "orig.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = MyWidget()
ex.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**uic_file.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(900, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0.246305 rgba(235, 197, 240, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_red = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_red.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_red.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";\n"
"color: rgb(14, 29, 41);")
        self.pushButton_red.setObjectName("pushButton_red")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('orig.png')
        self.image = QLabel(self)
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 740, 455))
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 740, 455))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("orig.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_green = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_green.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_green.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";\n"
"color: rgb(13, 23, 35);")
        self.pushButton_green.setObjectName("pushButton_green")
        self.pushButton_blue = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_blue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_blue.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_blue.setObjectName("pushButton_blue")
        self.pushButton_all = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_all.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_all.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_all.setObjectName("pushButton_all")
        self.pushButton_bright = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_bright.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_bright.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_bright.setObjectName("pushButton_bright")
        self.pushButton_left = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 260, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_left.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_left.setObjectName("pushButton_left")
        self.pushButton_right = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_right.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_right.setObjectName("pushButton_right")
        self.pushButton_negative = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_negative.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 380, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_negative.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_negative.setObjectName("pushButton_negative")
        self.pushButton_wb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_wb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 440, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_wb.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_wb.setObjectName("pushButton_wb")
        self.pushButton_gray = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_gray.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_gray.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_gray.setObjectName("pushButton_gray")
        self.pushButton_sepia = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_sepia.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_sepia.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_sepia.setObjectName("pushButton_sepia")
        self.pushButton_contrast = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_contrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_contrast.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_contrast.setObjectName("pushButton_contrast")
        self.pushButton_save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_save.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_save.setObjectName("pushButton_save")
        self.pushButton_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_download.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_download.setObjectName("pushButton_download")
        self.pushButton_orig = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_orig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(770, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_orig.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_orig.setObjectName("pushButton_orig")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "KotiKot"))
        self.pushButton_red.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RED"))
        self.pushButton_green.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GREEN"))
        self.pushButton_blue.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BLUE"))
        self.pushButton_all.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ALL"))
        self.pushButton_bright.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BRIGHT"))
        self.pushButton_left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LEFT"))
        self.pushButton_right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RIGHT"))
        self.pushButton_negative.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NEGATIVE"))
        self.pushButton_wb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "WB"))
        self.pushButton_gray.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GRAY"))
        self.pushButton_sepia.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SEPIA"))
        self.pushButton_contrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CONTRAST"))
        self.pushButton_save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAVE"))
        self.pushButton_download.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DOWNLOAD"))
        self.pushButton_orig.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ORIGINAL"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не проверял логику вашего приложения и не могу сказать все ли вы делаете правильно.

Я только исправил некоторые ошибки, которые у меня возникали и отредактировал два метода `save()` и `download()`. Я прокомментировал изменения, которые внес в ваше приложение. Проверьте, если что-то будет не понятно - спросите.

**main.py**

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import shutil
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#from uic_file import Ui_Dialog
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(900, 600)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qradialgradient(spread:pad, cx:0.5, cy:0.5, radius:0.5, fx:0.5, fy:0.5, stop:0.246305 rgba(235, 197, 240, 255), stop:1 rgba(255, 255, 255, 255));")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_red = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_red.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 10, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_red.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";\n"
"color: rgb(14, 29, 41);")
        self.pushButton_red.setObjectName("pushButton_red")
        
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)                   # ???
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(MainWindow)                           # ???
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('orig.png')
        self.image = QLabel(self)                                           # ??? 
        
        
        self.image.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 740, 455))
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 10, 740, 455))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("orig.png"))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_green = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_green.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 60, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_green.setStyleSheet("font: 13pt \".AppleSystemUIFont\";\n"
"color: rgb(13, 23, 35);")
        self.pushButton_green.setObjectName("pushButton_green")
        self.pushButton_blue = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_blue.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 110, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_blue.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_blue.setObjectName("pushButton_blue")
        self.pushButton_all = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_all.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 160, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_all.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_all.setObjectName("pushButton_all")
        self.pushButton_bright = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_bright.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 210, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_bright.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_bright.setObjectName("pushButton_bright")
        self.pushButton_left = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_left.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 260, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_left.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_left.setObjectName("pushButton_left")
        self.pushButton_right = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_right.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 320, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_right.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_right.setObjectName("pushButton_right")
        self.pushButton_negative = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_negative.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 380, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_negative.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_negative.setObjectName("pushButton_negative")
        self.pushButton_wb = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_wb.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 440, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_wb.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_wb.setObjectName("pushButton_wb")
        self.pushButton_gray = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_gray.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_gray.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_gray.setObjectName("pushButton_gray")
        self.pushButton_sepia = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_sepia.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_sepia.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_sepia.setObjectName("pushButton_sepia")
        self.pushButton_contrast = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_contrast.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_contrast.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_contrast.setObjectName("pushButton_contrast")
        self.pushButton_save = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_save.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_save.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_save.setObjectName("pushButton_save")
        self.pushButton_download = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_download.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(630, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_download.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_download.setObjectName("pushButton_download")
        self.pushButton_orig = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_orig.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(770, 490, 113, 32))
        self.pushButton_orig.setStyleSheet("color:rgb(11, 13, 31)")
        self.pushButton_orig.setObjectName("pushButton_orig")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "KotiKot"))
        self.pushButton_red.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RED"))
        self.pushButton_green.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GREEN"))
        self.pushButton_blue.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BLUE"))
        self.pushButton_all.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ALL"))
        self.pushButton_bright.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "BRIGHT"))
        self.pushButton_left.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "LEFT"))
        self.pushButton_right.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RIGHT"))
        self.pushButton_negative.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "NEGATIVE"))
        self.pushButton_wb.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "WB"))
        self.pushButton_gray.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GRAY"))
        self.pushButton_sepia.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SEPIA"))
        self.pushButton_contrast.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "CONTRAST"))
        self.pushButton_save.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "SAVE"))
        self.pushButton_download.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "DOWNLOAD"))
        self.pushButton_orig.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ORIGINAL"))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.imagePath = ''
        self.current = None                                            # !!! +++

        self.pushButton_red.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_green.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_blue.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_all.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.pushButton_bright.clicked.connect(self.bright)
        self.pushButton_left.clicked.connect(self.rotate)
        self.pushButton_right.clicked.connect(self.rotate)
        self.pushButton_negative.clicked.connect(self.negative)
        self.pushButton_wb.clicked.connect(self.wb)
        self.pushButton_gray.clicked.connect(self.gray)
        self.pushButton_sepia.clicked.connect(self.sepia)
        self.pushButton_contrast.clicked.connect(self.contrast)
        self.pushButton_save.clicked.connect(self.save)
        self.pushButton_download.clicked.connect(self.download)
        self.pushButton_orig.clicked.connect(self.orig)

    def contrast(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        avg = 0
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
# !!!
#               r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
# ---------------------> v <------------------------------------------------------
                r, g, b, a = im.getpixel((x, y))                         # !!! +++ 
                
                avg += r * 0.299 + g * 0.587 + b * 0.114
        avg /= width * height
        lst = []
        for i in range(256):
            temp = int(avg + 2 * (i - avg))
            if temp < 0:
                temp = 0
            elif temp > 255:
                temp = 255
            lst.append(temp)
        for x in range(width):
            for y in range(height):
# !!!
#                r, g, b = im.getpixel((x, y))
# ---------------------> v <------------------------------------------------------
                r, g, b, a = im.getpixel((x, y))

                draw.point((x, y), (lst[r], lst[g], lst[b]))

        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def sepia(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                all = (a + b + c) // 3
                a = all + 40 * 2
                b = all + 40
                c = all
                if (a > 255):
                    a = 255
                if (b > 255):
                    b = 255
                if (c > 255):
                    c = 255
                draw.point((i, j), (a, b, c))

        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def gray(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                all = (a + b + c) // 3
                draw.point((i, j), (all, all, all))

        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def wb(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                all = a + b + c
                if (all > (((255 - 100) // 2) * 3)):
                    a, b, c = 255, 255, 255
                else:
                    a, b, c = 0, 0, 0
                draw.point((i, j), (a, b, c))

        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def negative(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0]
                b = pix[i, j][1]
                c = pix[i, j][2]
                draw.point((i, j), (255 - a, 255 - b, 255 - c))
        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def bright(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        x, y = im.size
        pix = im.load()
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        width = im.size[0]
        height = im.size[1]
        for i in range(width):
            for j in range(height):
                a = pix[i, j][0] + 100
                b = pix[i, j][1] + 100
                c = pix[i, j][2] + 100
                if (a < 0):
                    a = 0
                if (b < 0):
                    b = 0
                if (c < 0):
                    c = 0
                if (a > 255):
                    a = 255
                if (b > 255):
                    b = 255
                if (c > 255):
                    c = 255
                draw.point((i, j), (a, b, c))

        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def run(self):
        im = Image.open("orig.png")
        pixels = im.load()
        x, y = im.size
        for i in range(x):
            for j in range(y):
#                r, g, b = pixels[i, j]
# ---------------------> v <------------------------------------------------------
                r, g, b, a  = pixels[i, j] 
                
                if (self.sender().text() == 'RED'):
                    pixels[i, j] = r, 0, 0
                elif (self.sender().text() == 'GREEN'):
                    pixels[i, j] = 0, g, 0
                elif (self.sender().text() == 'BLUE'):
                    pixels[i, j] = 0, 0, b
                else:
                    pass

        im.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

    def rotate(self):
        im = Image.open('orig.png')
        if (self.sender().text() == "RIGHT"):
            degree = -90
        else:
            degree = 90
        im2 = im.rotate(degree, expand=True)
        im2.save("upd.png")
        self.pixmap.load("upd.png")
        self.current = "upd.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

# !!! vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def save(self):

#        if self.imagePath:
        if self.current:                                                    # !!! +++
            options = QFileDialog.Options()
            options |= QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog
            fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
                self, "SaveFileName", "",
                "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)",
                options=options)
            if fileName:
                #print("файл для Сохранения: ", fileName)

                path = shutil.copy(self.current, fileName)                  # + path =
                
                msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(                    # +++
                    self,                                                   # +++
                    'Успех',                                                # +++
                    f'Текущий файл {self.current} \nсохранен в {path}.'     # +++
                    )                                                       # +++
        else:                                                               # +++
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.warning(                            # +++
                self,                                                       # +++
                'Внимание',                                                 # +++
                'Файл для сохранения не обозначен.'                         # +++
                )                                                           # +++
            return                                                          # +++

    def download(self):
        self.imagePath, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            self, 
            "Select Image", 
            "",
            "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.bmp)")
            
        if not self.imagePath:                                              # +++
            return                                                          # +++

        pixmap = QPixmap(self.imagePath)
# !!! +++        
#       self.image.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200))         # ? может self.image ?
# ???   v^v^v^v^v^ <---- ???               v^v^v^v^ <---- это надо ???
        self.label.setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(200, 200))          # ? self.label
# !!! +++
        self.label.setParent(None)         # я не знаю где вы хотите показать self.label
        self.label.show()                  # поэтому показываю в новом окне

# !!! ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    def orig(self):
        im = Image.open("orig.png")
        im.save("orig.png")
        self.pixmap.load("orig.png")
        self.current = "orig.png"
        self.image.setPixmap(self.pixmap)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**orig.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @oonostosiaa что не так?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, но я немного не понимаю как обработать уже загруженное фото, потому что всегда обрабатывается тот самый orig.png, а если же у файла другое имя, ничего не происходит

Comment: @oonostosiaa пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Если у вас возникли другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос, приложите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать , и что у вас не получается.

Comment: разобралась используя shutil)